# change element style in method callback

Tags: meteor

This code is trying to add a class to an element. the class definition is located in meteor_app_root/stylesheets/style.css `.wrongInput { color: red; }`
This method returns fine but the text inside the input element is not changing to red as I am expecting.

**edited**
I get browser console print "server returned" but the addClass line is not doing its work.

**edited**
changing the style from `color: Red;` to `border-color: Red;` makes the boarder colour red.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
Template.footer.events({
  'click button': function () {
   var doc = {};
   $('input').each(function () {
     this.value && (doc[this.name]=this.value)
   });
   
    Meteor.call('processInputs', doc, function (err, res) {
      if (res) {
        console.log("res   " + res);
        $('[name="plate"]').addClass("wrongInput");
      }
    });
  }
});


//server.js
Meteor.methods({
  processInputs: function (doc) {
    return "server acted";
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <form>
          <ul class="list-group">
            {{#each this.items}}
              <li>
                <input class="list-group-item basic-vertical-spacing col-xs-12" type="text"
                       name={{name}} placeholder={{placeholder}}>
              </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I kinda get the feel that some other CSS is overshadowing your `.wrongInput`. Did you check in the browser CSS inspector?

Comment: Seems to be css issue rather than meteor issue. I agree with @Blaze, your some css rules might be overridden. You can use css inspector in browser's developer tools and first apply .wrongInput manually to see if it has an expected behaviour.

Comment: for some unknown reason it started to work. I am clueless :(

Answer (score 0):

I see what it is, you didn't have the if(err):

```
Meteor.call('myFunction', function(err, data) {
  if (err)
  {
    $('[name="plate"]').addClass("wrongInput");
  }

});
```

Comment: Please see code update. The server is returning fine. the addClass code is not doing its work.

Comment: console.log($("[name='plate']").length); before addClass line return 1 which means there is an element, something in meteor which is not applying the class I guess :(